# Populate Dropdown only if dropdown is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I can't manage to find out how to initiate a click event by a user clicking on a dropdown.  I want to populate the dropdown ONLY if the user clicks the dropdown which will be rare.  In addition, it depends on several other values selected on the page.  So basically, how do I fire off an event if a user just simply clicks on the dropdown to see the options.

I've tried, `$('select').click` but to no avail.

It works if you don't have any options.  But if there are current options, no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/bGTug/) I've done it and its working.

```
$("select").on("click", function() {
    $(this).append("<option>1</option><option>2</option>");
});
```

**Updated**: http://jsfiddle.net/paska/bGTug/2/

New code:

```
var loaded = false;
$("select").on("click", function() {
    if (loaded)
        return;
    $(this).append("<option>1</option><option>2</option>");
    loaded = true;
});
```

Comment: better listen for the 'mousedown' otherwise the popup will be empty on first click. Also it will keep added the options on each subsequent click

Comment: This doensn't work if you already have options in your dropdown.

Comment: not sure if it's just me, but this doesn't work. I have to click on the dropdown 3 times before the list opens...

Comment: I made it with click because the question says so. I think is odd too. I've just corrected the script for the extra added options.

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/bGTug/3/ . When I add options and use an alert, no luck.

Comment: @KingKongFrog in yout jsfiddle you are not adding options. You removed the line which does it!

Comment: Here it is working adding options AND with the alert: http://jsfiddle.net/paska/bGTug/4/

Comment: Very odd, it doesn't alert either.  I wonder if there is something environment wise that's causing this

Comment: Regardless, Ive got it to work.  I have a feeling the alert is causing some issue, however regular function no issue.  Thx for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. It's really odd because I've just tested it in Chrome 23 and it works

Answer (score 9):

Try using the `focus` event instead, that way the `select` will be populated even when targeted using the keyboard.

```
$('select').on('focus', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.children().length == 1) {
        $this.append('<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>');
    }
});​
```

View simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/st3fan/NTxs8/).

**UPDATE**

Here is a [new version](http://jsfiddle.net/st3fan/DRQDb/) that uses [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to only fire the event handler once. This way you are able to use your `alert` without adding any `option` elements to change the outcome of the condition as the previous solution required.

```
$('select').on('focus', function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    // run your alert here if it´s necessary
    alert('Focused for the first time :)');

    // add the new option elements
    $this.append('<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>');

    // unbind the event to prevent it from being triggered again
    $this.unbind('focus');
});​
```

Hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually it keeps alerting if I replace it with an alert instead of adding options.

Comment: @KingKongFrog As you are not changing the number of child elements the condition keeps to evaluate as `true`.

Comment: Regardless, Ive got it to work.  I have a feeling the alert is causing some issue, however regular function no issue.  Thx for your help.

Comment: Updated my answer. Can also recommend using `console.log` rather than `alert` for debugging purposes. If you´re not developing for some really old browser :)

Comment: Slightly better but still doesn't work on most browsers. In IE 10 for example it takes two clicks to open the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the dropdown to automatically open after the click is trickier:

```
// Mousedown is used so IE works
$('#select_id').on('focus mousedown', function (e) {
    var data;
    $(this).off('focus mousedown');
    $.ajax({async: false, 
            type: 'GET', 
            url: 'url that returns the options',
            success: function (d) { data = d; }
           });
    $(this).find('option').remove().end().append(data);
    // Prevent IE hang by waiting awhile
    var t = new Date().getTime(); while(new Date().getTime() < t + 200) {}
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Great Answer Patrik, I was stuck in it from 2 days, and finally got out of this thanks alot